# After restoring from server backup, Jenkins stopped working

Tags: devops, cicd

in the logs the following information

```
The command journalctl -xe issues failrul
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit jenkins.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Dec 05 04:11:12 vwkdenicdn systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit jenkins.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit jenkins.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 10799 and the job result is done.
Dec 05 04:11:12 vwkdenicdn systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 05 04:11:12 vwkdenicdn systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit jenkins.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 05 04:11:12 vwkdenicdn systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit jenkins.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit jenkins.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 10799 and the job result is failed.
```

and

```
systemctl status jenkins.service

● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-12-05 04:11:12 UTC; 1min 41s ago
    Process: 137379 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 137379 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 05 04:11:12 vwkdenicdn systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 05 04:11:12 vwkdenicdn systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Dec 05 04:11:12 vwkdenicdn systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 05 04:11:12 vwkdenicdn systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 05 04:11:12 vwkdenicdn systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
```

Tried to update Jenkins as after the same error the first time it worked

and I also tried changing the Jenkins config and setting the version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_352"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_352-8u352-ga-1~20.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.352-b08, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the new version of django does not support version 8 of java

this command caused a problem when starting jenkins:

- journalctl -f --unit=jenkins

next, I'm just install java11:

- sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk

and change default java,

- sudo update-alternatives --config java

after this command choice java version by  number

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

### Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status

- 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press  to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0

next, start jenkins

- systemctl start jenkins.service